# send information from one form to another WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem: I have to Forms. One Form has dataGridView and a button. When you click the the button, creating Form2, where you input information. And these information need to add to dataGridView on First Form. But when i click button "Add" in Form2, 
I have an error NullReferenceException was unhandled(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.). Please help me!

Form1

```
private string client = null;
    private string driver = null;
    private string carModel = null;
    private string carKey=null;

    public string GoodsName2 = null;
    public string GoodsPrice2 = null;
    public string GoodsCount2 = null;
    AddWaybilGoods add_waibil_goods = null;

    public Waybil()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Base base_ = new Base(Share.server_address, Share.login, Share.password, Share.database);
        base_.fill_combo(comboClients, "Clients", "ClientsName");
        base_.fill_combo(comboDrivers, "Drivers", "DriversName");
        base_.fill_combo(comboModel, "Cars", "CarsModel");
    }

    private void Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client = comboClients.SelectedItem.ToString();
        driver = comboDrivers.SelectedItem.ToString();
        carModel = comboModel.SelectedItem.ToString();
        carKey =Key.Text.ToString();
        Word.Application word = new Word.Application();
        word.Visible = true;
        Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Add();
        doc.Select();
        word.Selection.TypeText(client);
        word.Selection.TypeText(driver);
        word.Selection.TypeText(carModel);
        word.Selection.TypeText(carKey);
    }

    private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        add_waibil_goods = new AddWaybilGoods();
        add_waibil_goods.Owner = this;
        add_waibil_goods.Show();
        add_waibil_goods.Focus();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(GoodsName2,GoodsPrice2, GoodsCount2);
        dataGridView1.Update();
    }

    private void comboModel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        carModel = comboModel.SelectedItem.ToString();
        Base base_ = new Base(Share.server_address, Share.login, Share.password, Share.database);
        base_.find_item(Key, "Cars", "CarsKey", "CarsModel", carModel);
    }
}
```

Form2

```
public partial class AddWaybilGoods : Form
{
    Waybil w_b = null;
    public string GoodsName1 = null;
    public string GoodsPrice1 = null;
    public string GoodsCount1 = null;

    public AddWaybilGoods()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        w_b= this.Owner as Waybil;
        Base base_ = new Base(Share.server_address, Share.login, Share.password, Share.database);
        base_.fill_combo(AddWaybilGoods1, "Goods", "GoodsName");
    }

    public void Добавить_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GoodsCount1 = Count.Text.ToString();
        w_b.GoodsName2 = this.GoodsName1;
        w_b.GoodsPrice2 = GoodsPrice1;
        w_b.GoodsCount2 = GoodsCount1;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void AddWaybilGoods1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GoodsName1 = AddWaybilGoods1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        Base base_ = new Base(Share.server_address, Share.login, Share.password, Share.database);
        base_.find_item(Price, "Goods","GoodsPrice", "GoodsName", GoodsName1);
        GoodsPrice1 = Price.Text.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: on which line you are getting exception ? please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the following statements should fix your issue

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    add_waibil_goods = new AddWaybilGoods();
    if (add_waibil_goods.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(add_waibil_goods.GoodsName2, add_waibil_goods.GoodsPrice2, add_waibil_goods.GoodsCount2);
        dataGridView1.Update();
    }
}
```

It appears that you were referencing the properties in Form1 when adding to the dataGridView1.  You will also need to start the form2 as a modal window.  A modal window will ensure that the user fills in the correct data before the application continues.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For accessing `Form1` public members in `Form2` you can send same instance to Form1 in the constructor.

See following code:

**Form1**:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    add_waibil_goods = new AddWaybilGoods(this); //parameterized constructor       
    add_waibil_goods.Show(this); //assign owner
    add_waibil_goods.Focus();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(GoodsName2,GoodsPrice2, GoodsCount2);
    dataGridView1.Update();
}
```

**Form2**:

```
public partial class AddWaybilGoods : Form
{
    Waybil w_b = null;
    public string GoodsName1 = null;
    public string GoodsPrice1 = null;
    public string GoodsCount1 = null;

    public AddWaybilGoods(Waybil wb)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        w_b= wb;
        Base base_ = new Base(Share.server_address, Share.login, Share.password, Share.database);
        base_.fill_combo(AddWaybilGoods1, "Goods", "GoodsName");
    }
    //... other methods
}
```